# ExoPlayer inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I'm trying to implement recyclerview that plays video int the view itself.
I'm using exoplayer for video playback
When I play videos sequentially from top to bottom the screen starts to flicker, but when I play from bottom to top everything works fine.

Also flickering happens on Android kitkat and not on Marshmallow

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/eneim/toro and see if it helps?

Comment: did you ever fix this ? is it related to being in a recyclerview? Im getting the same, videos wobble a bit when they start or pause.